# Where should I store configuration information in ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, settings

I have an ASP.NET application.
It resides within another ASP.NET application.
I put my DLL in the other apps bin folder and have a subdirectory with my aspx files.
I can't edit the main app's Web.config.

So where can I store configuration settings?
For example, this is an app that will get deployed to various clients. I want to store the client name used for display in the headers and such. And the location of a logo file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a web.config file on the folder your ASPX files reside and .NET will take care of nesting them and aggregate its contents.

Comment: When I did that before the app complained.  I can try it and see what it complains about.

Comment: Maybe you can try trimming the inner web.config to only include the set of attributes you need in your subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Settings.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) to store it. [This example](http://dotnetperls.com/Content/Settings-Visual-Studio.aspx) might help. You can have multiple settings files and access any of them, just as you would for any other class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a Settings.config XML file and put it wherever you want (the .config extension will prevent it from being viewable through an HTTP request), then wrap it with a Settings class and talk to that Settings class from your application.